# Tecla de atalho para paginação PHP e Mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma paginação feita em PHP e Mysql:

```
$sqlVisualizarContar = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM tabela;");

$maximo = 10;

if($pagina >= 1){

   $inicio = $pagina * $maximo;

   $totalPag = mysqli_num_rows($sqlVisualizarContar) / $maximo;

}else{

  $inicio = 0;

  $maximo = 10;

}
if($pagina < 1){

    $paginacao = "<a href=\"?pag=".($pagina + 1)."\" class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' style='background-color: #DA9139; color: #fff'>Próximo <i class=\"fa fa-angle-double-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> </a>";

}else{

$anterior = ($pagina - 1);

    if($anterior == 0){

       $pgAnterior = "visualizar-produtos.php";

    }else{

       $pgAnterior = "\"?pag=".$anterior."\"";

    }

    $proximo = ($pagina + 1);

    $pgProximo = "\"?pag=".$proximo."\"";


$paginacao = "<a href='visualizar-produtos.php' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' style='background-color: #DA9139; color: #fff'> Primeira Página </a>&nbsp;";

    $paginacao .= "<a href=".$pgAnterior." class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' style='background-color: #DA9139; color: #fff'> <i class=\"fa fa-angle-double-left\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> Anterior </a>&nbsp;";

if($pagina != ceil($totalPag - 1)){

      $paginacao .= "<a href=".$pgProximo." class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' style='background-color: #DA9139; color: #fff'> Próximo <i class=\"fa fa-angle-double-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> </a> &nbsp;";

      $paginacao .= "<a href=\"?pag=".ceil($totalPag - 1)."\" class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' style='background-color: #DA9139; color: #fff'> Última Página </a>&nbsp;";

    }
}

sqlVisualizar = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT ".$inicio.",".$maximo.";");
```

Como resultado, obtenho dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o usuário para mudar de página, ele tem que clicar nos números, seta ou na palavra **Última**. Gostaria de saber é possível usar também teclas de atalho para mudar de página. Se sim, como eu faria isso?

Comment: Eai jovem, a resposta atende ao que foi pedido? Senão, me deixe saber qual o problema que tento melhorar a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um *listener* para o evento `onkeydown` em `document` e validar se a tecla pressionada tem código 37 (seta para esquerda) ou 39 (seta para a direita). 38 e 40 são, respectivamente, os códigos das setas para cima e para baixo.

```js
const ultimaPagina = 4;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  
  const elemento = document.querySelector('#atual');
  let pagAtual = parseInt(elemento.innerHTML);
  
  if(e.keyCode == 37 && pagAtual > 1) {
    elemento.innerHTML = --pagAtual;
    console.log('Página anterior');
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39 && pagAtual < ultimaPagina) {
    elemento.innerHTML = ++pagAtual;
    console.log('Próxima página');
  }    
};
```

```html
<div id="pagina">
  Página atual: <span id="atual">1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá LINQ. Desculpe a demora. Obrigado.